# compute speed in for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

I have the problem when I compute in a matrix. This problem is about the speed of computation.

I have a matrix of binary image (f), I find conected component by bwlabel in matlab. [L num]=bwlabel(f);

after that base on some property I found a vector p that include some value of L that I need to remove. this is my code and explanation

```
function [f,L] = clear_nontext(f,L,nontext)
% p is a vector include a lot of value we need to remove
p=find(nontext(:)~=0);
% example p= [1 2 9 10 100...] that mean we need to find in L matrix where get the value =1,2,9,10,100..] and remove it   
[a b]=size(L);
g=zeros(a,b);
for u=1:length(p)
    for i=1:a
        for j=1:b
        if L(i,j)==p(u)
            g(i,j)=1;
            %L(i,j)=500000;
            f(i,j)=0;
        end
        end
    end
end
end
```

When I use this way, program run but it is so slow, because with one value of p we need to check all value in matrix f (or L) again. So I need another way to run it faster. Could you help me?

Thank you so much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, MATLAB performs matrix operations (or index operations) faster then loops.
You can try the following:

```
g(ismember(L,p)) = 1;
f(ismember(L,p)) = 1;
```

EDIT:
I was curious so I ran a little test:

```
L = round(20*randn(10000,10000));
f = L;
p = 1:5;

[a b]=size(L);
g=zeros(a,b);

tic;
for u=1:length(p)
    for i=1:a
        for j=1:b
            if L(i,j)==p(u)
                g(i,j)=1;
                f(i,j)=0;
            end
        end
    end
end
toc
```

for which I got:

```
Elapsed time is 38.960842 seconds.
```

When I tried the following:

```
tic;
g(ismember(L,p)) = 1;
f(ismember(L,p)) = 0;
toc
```

I got

```
Elapsed time is 5.735137 seconds.
```

Comment: In real, when I try with my matrix, the time is similar with my code. I think because my matrix L is the matrix of connected component so the value of (i,j) and neighbor are the same. and the value of (i,j) is unique at one region ( no similar value in another region of matrix L). I think we need another algorithm base on this property. thank so much ? do you have any ideas?